# opencv 2.4.2 Configuration with Visual Studio 2010 issue?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

Recently I decided to make a switch from OpenCV 2.1 to Opencv 2.4. I am having problems in configuring it with opencv. The details are as follows:-

1. Installed and extracted opencv in folder( opencv2.4).
2. Created a new folder "BIN" inside (opencv2.4). Used CMAKE to extract all data in BIN.
3. While using CMAKE I did not select QT, TBB, IPP options.
4. I added path to System environment i.e. C:\opencv2.4\build\x64\vc10\bin;
5. I used the solution in "BIN" folder and compiled first with Debug and then with Release options.
6. Now I started a new VS2010 project.
7. In project properties; C++ -> General[image]
8. In project properties;Linker-> General I did[image]
9. In project properties;Linker-> Input I did [image]
10. I finally copied all .dll files in my debug folder.
11. When I run program, I am getting following error.[image]
12. I dont know what wrong I am doing. Somehow I think I am not linking the library properly. Plz guide me in this regard .  . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are extensive tutorials coming with the official OpenCV installation. They explain in great detail, with a lot of screenshots, how you configure Visual Studio with OpenCV. You can read the documentation online. I'll link the two tutorials relevant to this question:

- **Installation in Windows**

  - http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html
- **How to build applications with OpenCV inside the Microsoft Visual Studio**

  - http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html

Comment: i think i am following all the steps; that's why i requested here as i cannot figure out my wrong thing . . .

Comment: In the tutorial I see only one additional include directory, the OpenCV libs in the linker settings are not given as full path...

Comment: i did everything again to make sure. same error message again unresolved external symbols . . dont know what's happening. I checked my opencv is successfully installed as I am able to run some exes from debug and release folder. I am doing something wrong in linking the project. I dont knwo what

Comment: You accepted, so what was wrong with your configuration? Maybe you can drop a note on your solution here, for people having similar problems.

Comment: hi, i solved the problem. The only problem was that I have 64 bit mahcine but my Visual Studio 2010 is 32 bit. While using CMAKE, I was using VS2010 64 bit version to compile opencv libraries. So it was creating problem in linking. Now everything is working perfectly fine. once again thanks to everyone for help.

Comment: You know, you can also write an answer yourself and accept it. :)

Comment: Yes, there are tutorials, but every time I tried to install opencv with visual studio I had problems. At least when using cmake findopencv.cmake. The problem is the folder structure, too complex.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the opencv_legacy242.. lib. Add it and try again. Some functionality has moved to legacy in latest release

Answer (score 0):

You may also try follow videos on this subject. They help a lot. Those from a reliable source of course. I know there's one on opencv.org website.